# Longest subsequence whose sum is divisible by k

Tags: c++, algorithm, sum, dynamic-programming, subsequence

I am practicing some Dynamic Programming problems and encounter this problem

Given an array of `n(1<=n<=1000)` integers and a positive integer `k(k<=1000)`. Find the longest subsequence whose sum is divisible by `k`.

For example, `a = [1,6,11,5,10,15,20,2,4,9]` and `k=5`.

The result should be: `[9,4,20,15,10,5,11,6]` because `9+4+20+15+10+5+11+6 = 80`, which is divisible by 5.

What is a suitable approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: So we can assume it is not contiguously embedded within the array?

Comment: Seems like the subset sum problem. Add up all the numbers. The total is 83. So then the question becomes, "Is there a subset that sums to 3?" In the example, the subset {1,2} exists and we're done. If no subset sums to 3, then you would need to try 8, then 13, then 18, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the longest possible subsequence, the array itself. Calculate its sum modulo k. If its zero, we are done. Otherwise, find a number such that its modulo k is the same. If that exists, remove it and we are done. Otherwise keep going.

Comment: Your algorithm is ambiguous if you don't find a number with the same modulo.

Comment: @Mansoor OP asked for an *approach*, not a complete solution.

Comment: agreed, just a note.

Answer (score 2):

**Brute Force Approach:**

We can generate all the possible sub-sequences and then find the largest sub-sequence among them whose sum is divisible by `K`.

However, the time complexity of this approach will be `O(n*n)`.

**Efficient Approach:**

We can use ***dynamic programming*** here. Kindly note that this approach will only work for small values of `K`.

```
dp[i][curr_mod] = max(dp[i + 1][curr_mod], dp[i + 1][(curr_mod + arr[i]) % m] + 1)
```

Here, `dp[i][curr_mod]` stores the longest subsequence of subarray `arr[i…N-1]` such that the sum of this subsequence and `curr_mod` is divisible by `K`.

At each step, either `index i` can be chosen to update `curr_mod` or it can be ignored.

Also, note that only *SUM % m* needs to be stored instead of the entire sum as this information is sufficient to complete the states of DP.